# recursive program in r

Tags: r, recursion, mapply

I am doing some computations, but am having a hard time wrining a program in r that accomplishes what I need.

```
x1<-c('a','b','c','d','a')
x2<-c('b','e','g')
x3<-c('c','a','h','j')
x4<-c('d','l','m','o','p','x','y','z')
x5<-c('f','q','a')
```

I am looking of a way to compute

```
y1<-length(intersect(x1,x2))
y2<-length(intersect(x3, union(x1,x2)))
y3<-length(intersect(x4, union(x3,union(x1,x2))))
y4<-length(intersect(x5, union(x4, union(x3,union(x1,x2)))))
```

Comment: I suspect you would do better to have your vectors in a list, then you can do `x[[i]]` and `x[[j]]` etc operating over whatever combinations of indices you need.

Comment: May be `lst <- mget(paste0('x', 1:5));lst1 <-  Reduce(union, lst, accumulate=TRUE);lengths(Map(intersect, lst[3:5], lst1[-c(1,length(lst1))]))`

Comment: @plafort Yes, it is.  The first one is `intersect(x1, x2)` where no `union` comes.  So, I thought it can be manually computed, and the last one `y5` is not needed by the OP.

Comment: @Frank, thanks for pointing out my mistakes. I have revised the terms.

Comment: @akrun You can compare your result with y1-y4. Looks right, except omitting y1. You might as well post it as an answer. Here's a variation that gets all of them: `nx  <- 5L; xx  <- mget(paste0('x', 1:nx)); cux <- Reduce(union, xx, accumulate=TRUE); lengths(Map(intersect, xx[-1], cux[-nx] )) ` Cool to see that `accumulate`; I never noticed that option before.

Comment: @akun, yes this will work well with my data. If you would like to post it as an answer I will mark it as solved.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the modified code.  Looks better. Hope you don't mind if I post it.  Also `akrun/akun/akn/.... anything is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the modified code from @Frank

```
 nx <- 5L
 xx <- mget(paste0('x', 1:nx))
 cux <- Reduce(union, xx, accumulate=TRUE)
 lengths(Map(intersect, xx[-1], cux[-nx] ))
```